# Licensing software that should be free for using with free RDBMS

Tags: license-recommendation

We want to make our software free for using with free RDBMS (and commercial for using with commercial RDBMS). What is the best way to do this?

We haven't found any public well-known license for that, so, the way I see it, we have 2 options:
1. Write our own license (which is not good because everyone should read it, and not everyone would do that).
2. Use some free license without right to modify software (and not including support of commercial RDBC in the distribution package under that license). Also we want to make our software open-source in time. But the problem is that we also have not found any public well-known for that (i.e. free or free open-source license without (!) right of modification).

So maybe someone can suggest something? Maybe we are missing something simple in that situation?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a request for a non-free licence,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will find no free licence that doesn't permit modifications: two of [the four freedoms](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.html) are the freedom to change the program, and the freedom to distribute modified copies; if the users can't do that, the software is not free.  Restrictions on commercial usage are also non-free, as the first freedom is to be able to run the program for any purpose.

Creative Commons' [BY-NC-ND](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-nd/4.0/) licence mostly fills your needs, if I understand them, but even CC notes *this is not a free culture license*, so you will face pushback if you try to describe your software as free when it is so licensed.  Also, the CC licences are not thought to be well-suited to software, and your definition of "non-commercial" (zero-cost when used with free RDBMSs, but non-zero-cost when used with commercial RDBMSs) doesn't exactly match CC's definition of "non-commercial".

You may be reduced to drafting your own licence, which (as you note) isn't a good idea.  I might suggest that you rethink what you wish to permit, or just make a piece of commercial software, and release it as such.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Actually under the term "free" I meant "free-to-use" (however I understand that the meaning of that word has changed a long time to go).The main idea is to be free "in free stack", and commercial "in commercial stack". In theory GPL and dual licensing (like MySQL) might help, but GPL does not restrict using with / over commercial software.

Comment: And is there some public license similar to Java license? It's free-to use, but you can not modify it (i.e. JVM) as far as I understand, but their license is not public.

Comment: We don't deal in non-free licences round here.  Just being zero-cost isn't enough.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, forgot about this. Thanks anyway.